# Changing to Xbox series S

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

My Xbox one has just broke down so I'm buying an xbox series S, but i'm worried all my games and their accesories will be lost, like all the skins I bought on Fortnite, or are all these held in my gaming account. I understand i'll have to download the games again, just want to know if my gamming acount keeps all the stuff i've bought?

Answer (score 1):

For single player games, it would be if Xbox has cloud saves and the game is compatible on both XB1 and XB Series S.

But you are talking about Fortenite, and for that, its easy. Your progress, for pretty much all online multiplayer games is linked to your Xbox Live Account, or your Epic Games account. (I dont know if Fortenite forces you to connect to an epic games account, but if it does that means only your epic games account is what contains your progress)

So just log into the same account you used to play on and everything should be there.

And since Fortenite is cross platform, you are not limited to the Xbox universe. You could play on PC and Playstation and even mobile and keep your progress.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, that's reassuring.